# Javascript | Making an image appear for one slide in Choose your own Adventure, then disappear?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm learning JS and building a project based on a choose your own adventure text game.

What I would like, is on certain 'slides', for images to appear with the description text in the top half.

The way it works right now is that the slides are changed by the option choices pointing to a new slide id, which has a new value for `text`. That is then used to update the actual text element. My initial thought was to have an empty `<img>` div, and then on certain slides have a variable update with `test.png` and use `.src` to give the div an image. However, this just means theres an ugly "no image found square" that shows up all the time.

Then I thought that perhaps on certain slides, I could assign a number to a variable `image`. This number would refer to an item in an array or list or something which is the image I want to show. The `showTextNode` function would then be checking for that number, and if it finds it, it will append an img child with the correct image. Then, moving to the next slide, the child would be removed.

My initial attempts to add an `if` loop checking if `image` is equal to a number do nothing except break everything! Right now, this solution is very much out of my wheelhouse, so if anyone can direct me to the right documentation or a guide or etc ... to learn about this, that would be awesome!

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script defer src="game.js"></script>
    <title>Case Study 1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container-upper">
            <div id="text" class="text">Text</div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-lower">
            <div id="option-buttons" class="btn-grid">
                <button class="btn">Option 1</button>
                <button class="btn">Option 2</button>
                <button class="btn">Option 3</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
const textElement = document.getElementById('text')
const optionButtonsElement = document.getElementById('option-buttons')

let state = {}

function startGame() {
    state = {};
    showTextNode(1);
}

function showTextNode(textNodeIndex) {
    const textNode = textNodes.find(textNode => textNode.id === textNodeIndex);
    textElement.innerText = textNode.text;
    while(optionButtonsElement.firstChild) {
        optionButtonsElement.removeChild(optionButtonsElement.firstChild);
    }

    textNode.options.forEach(option => {
        if(showOption(option)) {
            const button = document.createElement('button');
            button.innerText = option.text;
            button.classList.add('btn')
            button.addEventListener('click', () => selectOption(option));
            optionButtonsElement.appendChild(button);
        }
    })
}

function showOption(){
    return true;
}

function selectOption(option) {
    const nextTextNodeId = option.nextText;
    state = Object.assign(state, option.setState)
    showTextNode(nextTextNodeId)
}

const textNodes = [
    {
        id: 1,
        text: 'Case Study: BioPharma Expansion',
        options: [
            {
                text: 'Start',
                setState: {},
                nextText: 2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text: 'Your client is BioPharma, a multinational healthcare company headquartered in the Netherlands',
        options: [
            {
                text: "I'd like to know more about BioPharma's revenue",
                setState: {},
                nextText: 3
            },
            {
                text: "I'd like to know more about BioPharma's cost structure",
                setState: {},
                nextText: 3
            }   
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        text: "BioPharma's revenue has increased year on year by 12% since 2014",
        options: [
            {
                text: "What about costs?",
                setState: {},
                nextText: 4
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        text: "BioPharma's cost structure is shown below in Figure 1",
        options: [
            {
                text: "Here is some stuff",
            }
        ]
    }
]

startGame();
```

Comment: Just thinking now, maybe instead I can have the img div there always. But then I add and remove a class that makes it hidden or shown? Then I can update the link with .src for the relevant slides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option that I thought of is to insert an image as a background for a div. So I'm not entirely sure if I understood correctly what you are trying to achieve but it seems to me that depending on the "textNodes" object the user is in, you would like to display an image.

Keeping your code as close as possible to what you provided, I added an "imageLink" property to the object with a link as it's value and in your "showTextNode" function I added a ternary operator that looks up for that property, if it's not undefined then it will add that link as a background image to a div with the id="image", otherwise it set the display to none.

```js
const textElement = document.getElementById('text')
const optionButtonsElement = document.getElementById('option-buttons')

let state = {}

function startGame() {
    state = {};
    showTextNode(1);
}

function showTextNode(textNodeIndex) {
    const textNode = textNodes.find(textNode => textNode.id === textNodeIndex);
    textElement.innerText = textNode.text;
    
    while(optionButtonsElement.firstChild) {
        optionButtonsElement.removeChild(optionButtonsElement.firstChild);
    }
  
    // ternary operator that looks for the imageLink property
            textNode.imageLink ? document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage = `url(${textNode.imageLink})` : document.getElementById('image').style.display = "none"

    textNode.options.forEach(option => {

    // if statement removed as it will always returns true since that is the purpose of the function called
            const button = document.createElement('button');
            button.innerText = option.text;
            button.classList.add('btn')
            button.addEventListener('click', () => selectOption(option));
            optionButtonsElement.appendChild(button);
    })
}

// function commented as it's purpose seems redundant
/*
function showOption(){
    return true;
}
*/

function selectOption(option) {
    const nextTextNodeId = option.nextText;
    state = Object.assign(state, option.setState)
    showTextNode(nextTextNodeId)
}

const textNodes = [
    {
        id: 1,
        text: 'Case Study: BioPharma Expansion',
      // image link propert
      // change the link as you see fit
                imageLink: "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/1828/1828743.png",
        options: [
            {
                text: 'Start',
                setState: {},
                nextText: 2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text: 'Your client is BioPharma, a multinational healthcare company headquartered in the Netherlands',
        options: [
            {
                text: "I'd like to know more about BioPharma's revenue",
                setState: {},
                nextText: 3
            },
            {
                text: "I'd like to know more about BioPharma's cost structure",
                setState: {},
                nextText: 3
            }   
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        text: "BioPharma's revenue has increased year on year by 12% since 2014",
        options: [
            {
                text: "What about costs?",
                setState: {},
                nextText: 4
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        text: "BioPharma's cost structure is shown below in Figure 1",
        options: [
            {
                text: "Here is some stuff",
            }
        ]
    }
]

startGame();
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-upper">
    <div id="text" class="text">Text</div>
    
    <!-- Container where the image will be inserted -->
    <div id="image" style="width: 150px; height: 150px; background-repeat: no-repeat"></div>
    
  </div>
  <div class="container-lower">
    <div id="option-buttons" class="btn-grid">
      <button class="btn">Option 1</button>
      <button class="btn">Option 2</button>
      <button class="btn">Option 3</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you so much. That's super awesome, I've been reading up on ternary operators and the functionality is perfect. (To clarify the seemingly useless code, the `showOption` function would check for a condition, which would feed into the `if` statement. e.g. if a user had gone down a certain path and retrieved certain information, when they reached another point in the logic tree there would be a check as to whether they had found the required information. Otherwise, one of the options would not be displayed!)